# microphone input volume is too low, 14.04

Tags: 14.04, microphone, input

Microphone input volume is too low, so that the other part, while on video call, can hardly hear me!

Lonovo laptop g570.

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
```

Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Have you tried turning it up? If that doesn't help, post the make and model of the PC, and add the output of `aplay -l` to the question.

Answer (score 4):

List mic sink using following command:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

e.g: `$ pactl list short sinks`

o/p:

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Set mic sink volume using following command:

```
pactl set-sink-volume <index number if mic sink> <volume in %>
```

Make sure to setting mic volume you have to use mic sink index number.

e.g:

```
$ pactl set-sink-volume 0 70%
```